# Is there anything wrong with the strpos implementation in below case?

Tags: php, string, if-statement, strpos

I've a variable which contains comma separated strings. This is generated dynamically from the  array elements by using `implode()` function.So sometimes it contains nothing, sometimes it contains 1/2/3/4 strings separated by comma. I want to check whether the stirng Other is present within this comma separated string and if it's present then do the commands written inside if. But I'm facing a issue in which it's never detecting the string `"Other"` inside the comma separated values though tit's present. Can anyone help me in this regard please?
For your reference following is my code:

```
$form_data['que_issue'] = implode(",", $request['que_issue']);

if(strpos($form_data['que_issue'],"Other")) { 
    echo "In If"; 
    die;
    if(!$this->mValidator->validate($form_data['que_issue_comment'], "required", "true"))
        $this->mValidator->push_error($errors_msgs['que_issue_comment_blank'], 'que_issue_comment');
    elseif(!$this->mValidator->validate($form_data['que_issue_comment'], 'maxlength', '100'))
        this->mValidator->push_error($errors_msgs['que_issue_comment_length_invalid'], 'que_issue_comment');
} else
    echo "In a else"; 
die;//Its always going in else part only
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `Other` occur in the begin of the string, `strpos` return `0` and your condition fails. You have to add comparison with `false`: `strpos($form_data['que_issue'],"Other" !== false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strpos will return `0` if string match at the begin of the string. But `0` is interpreted as false by PHP.

Always look the documentation and see what is the specific return type/value when the method "fail" and compare against that. In this case

```
if(strpos($form_data['que_issue'],"Other") !== false)
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try something like this

```
if (strpos($form_data['que_issue'],'Other') !== false) {
```